# Using Meteor to create SVG in template works, but not in #each loop

Tags: svg, meteor, each, handlebars.js

Update: as of February 2014, Meteor supports reactive SVG, so no workaround is necessary.

Meteor 0.5.9

I would like to create a group of shapes, one for each document in the collection.  I can create shapes one at a time in a template, but not inside of an {{#each loop}}.

This works:

```
<Template name="map">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 500 600" version="1.1">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill={{color}}/>
  </svg>
</Template>

Template.map.color = function() {
  return "green";
};
```

This does not:

```
<Template name="map">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 500 600" version="1.1">
    {{#each colors}}
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill={{color}}/>
    {{/each}}
  </svg>
</Template>

Template.map.colors = function() {
  return [{color: "red"}, {color: "blue"}];
}
```

Anything I try to create inside of  using {{#each}} just doesn't show up, even though I can create them manually, even with attributes inserted by Meteor through the template.

I also tried just sending a single object {color: "red"} to the template and using {{#with colors}}, and that does not work either.  In addition to the SVG, I've also put plain s into the templates to make sure information gets to the template correctly, and those are all working as expected, with {{#each}} and with {{#with}}.

Should I be able to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the same problem experimenting with Meteor and SVG elements and discovered that you can add elements and get them to show up with the two methods below. One option is to just wrap the elements in the each loop in an `<svg></svg>`, like this:

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
{{#each pieces}}
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="{{x}}" cy="{{y}}" r="1" fill="{{color}}"></circle></svg>
{{/each}}
</svg>
```

Another options is to (on template render) create an svg element with jQuery that contains the element you want to insert, then use jQuery to grab that inner element and insert it into the svg element already in the DOM, like so (in coffeescript):

```
for piece in Pieces.find().fetch()
  $el = $("<svg><circle cx='#{piece.x}' cy='#{piece.y}' r='1' class='a'></circle></svg>")
  $el.find('circle').appendTo @$('svg')
```

You could also use something like d3 or RaphaelJS to do the inserting. You can even make the individual elements reactive to your Collection and animate easily by using a library like d3 in the Collection observer callbacks like so (again, coffeescript):

```
Pieces.find().observe {

  added: (piece)=>
    # using jquery (could use d3 instead)
    $el =  $("<svg><circle cx='#{piece.x}' cy='#{piece.y}' r='1' fill='#{piece.color}' data-id='#{piece._id}'></circle></svg>")
    $el.find('circle').appendTo @$('svg')

  changed: (newPiece, oldPiece)=>
    # using d3 to animate change
    d3.select("[data-id=#{oldPiece._id}]").transition().duration(1000).attr {
      cx: newPiece.x
      cy: newPiece.y
      fill: newPiece.color
    }

  removed: (piece)=>
    @$("[data-id=#{piece._id}]").remove()
}
```

These methods seem to work in latest Chrome, Safari, Firefox browsers on Mac, but I haven't tested in others.

Comment: I would not have thought to wrap each individual element in its own svg tags.   This doubles the number of elements being created, but it does work!

Comment: Now a branch of Meteor supports SVG! It's not part of the official release yet, but you can just do `meteor update --release blaze-rc0` and your SVG elements will update just like any other html template elements. More info here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze

Answer (score 3):

(Updated April 1, 2013)

Found  a way that combines Handlebars with insertion by Javascript. Have to give credit to this blog entry for figuring this one out:
http://nocircleno.com/blog/svg-and-handlebars-js-templates/

I created the following two files, placed them inside the *client* folder of a new Meteor directory and I got the html successfully.

**Testing.js:**

```
<head>
  <title>testing</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<template name="map">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    {{#each colors}}
      <rect x="0" y="{{yPosition}}" width="100" height="100" fill="{{color}}"/>
    {{/each}}
  </svg>
</template>
```

**Testing.html:**

```
(function () {

  var count = 0;

  Template.map.yPosition = function() {
    count++;
    return (count-1) * 100;
  };  

  Template.map.colors = function() {
    return [{color: "red"}, {color: "blue"}];
  };

  Meteor.startup(function() {
    var svgElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    svgElement.width = 500;
    svgElement.height = 600;
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(svgElement);
    var svgFragment = new DOMParser().parseFromString(Template.map(), "text/xml");
    svgElement.appendChild(svgFragment.documentElement);
  }); 

})();
```

Comment: I am not getting the same results.  The elements are created successfully, but they are not visible.  After a lot of research on this I'm pretty confident the issue is that you cannot add SVG elements after the SVG canvas has been created due to them being in a different namespace.  I've been successful adding them in javascript but not in a handlebars template like this.

Comment: Oups! you're right, I just assumed nothing was being displayed because my server wasn't set up to deliver SVG (btw, this was a great way to refresh my SVG knowledge). See my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Using Blaze](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze) page, Meteor will have first class support of SVG when Blaze is released.